# angular 2+ how to use and listen output emiter when use createComponent factory

Tags: angular, dynamic, components, output, emit

I create dynamically component in ParentComp:

```
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<ChildComp>(component);
this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
this.componentRef.instance.dataConfig = dataTab.dataConfig;
```

and need now emit some result from this ChildComp and listen this @output from ParentComp.

How can i get this data emitted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved easily like below

In child component

```
 @Output() close = new EventEmitter<any>();

  emitEventMethodInChild() {
    this.close.emit('close')
  }
```

In parent component

```
this.componentRef.instance.close.subscribe(response => {
    console.log('response from child to parent',response);
   // Here you can receive data output form child to parent component
}
```

Here, in the above example I took close as event emitter.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Don't forget to unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks